# Installing Test-unit-full On JRuby

Tags: cucumber, jruby, testunit

I would like to use assertions in my cucumber tests such as this:

Then /^I am taken to the page for that item$/ do

```
assert_equal page.find(:xpath, "//h2").text.to_s, $title, "The title you clicked does not match the title on the item page"
```

end

I have installed the test-unit gem, however, when I run my test, I get this error:

undefined method `assert_equal' for #<Object:0x81a> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/support/web_steps.rb:49:in`/^I am taken to the page for that item$/'
      features/userjourney.feature:15:in `Then I am taken to the page for that item'

After googling for a while, it looks like perhaps I need to install the test-unit-full gem. However, I tried this (using jRuby) and got this error:

ERROR:  Error installing test-unit-full:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library.
         Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.

Do I really need the test-unit-full gem in order to use assertions? And secondly, if so, how can I install the gem on jRuby?

Thanks,
Rebecca

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need test-unit-full to use assert_equal. Sorry if this is a silly question, but do you have

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
```

at the top of your script? I ran into something similar a while ago and it turns out that without the `gem` call I was using an older version of test-unit that came bundled with ruby1.8, rather than the latest version (2.3.0).